# Add a skewed background to DIV using CSS3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a custom page header set within a WordPress theme which simply displays a background image and some custom text that is added on top of the image.

Currently the header looks like this:

[image]

I would like to add a skewed background bar to the text that is imposed on top of the background image so that it looks like this:
[image]

The skewed div would give gradient backgrounds to both the header and subheader text. I am trying to created the graient divs using the CSS pseudo selector `::before` tag.

My issues are that the text is actually contained within a `Container` div which sets the width of the containing div.

I am trying to get the `Summer Sale` div background to but up close to the left hand browser window edge. This would mean it would have to break out of the container. I would like to do the same for the `subheader` text.

Also I am finding that currently the width of the `summer sale` spans the whole width of the containing div as pictured. I am not after this. I would like it to only span the width of the `summer sale` text.

Here are my code snippets:

**HTML Code**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col span_6">
            <h1>Summer Sale</h1>
            <span class="subheader">Save big on selected products</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS Code**

```
#page-header-bg h1::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border-right-width: 4px;
    border-right-style: solid;
    -webkit-transition: background .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: background .2s ease-in-out;
}
#page-header-bg h1::before, #page-header-bg .subheader::before {
    -webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(20deg);
    transform: skew(20deg)
}
#page-header-bg h1::before, #page-header-bg .subheader::before {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.35) 60%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(0,0,0,0)), color-stop(60%, rgba(0,0,0,0.35)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.35) 60%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.35) 60%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.35) 60%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.35) 60%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#40000000', GradientType=1 );
}
#page-header-bg .subheader, #page-header-bg h1 {
    position: relative
}
#page-header-bg .subheader::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    z-index: -1;
    padding: 0px 5px 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 6px
}
```

I thought about setting the width of the `#page-header-bg h1::before` tag however I cannot do that as the text will change and I can;t know what the width will be.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `h1` to `display:inline-block` and `width:auto` so it doesn't run full width and your `:before` should then adjust also based on text width

Comment: Great, thanks @charlietfl . That worked for containing the width of the main h1 header text. Now I have an issue with the subheader width. I couldn't display it as `display:inline-block` because it sits in the same position as the header. I had to change `.subheader { display: block }` to make it sit under the header.

Any idea on how to make the gradient sit flush on the left side window?

Comment: be easier to help with a live demo to allow modifying css right in browser dev tools

Comment: Can you see the subheader gradient spanning the whole width of the div

Comment: do an `:after` on h1 that is block

Comment: If I set both elements, the `h1` and the `.subheader` to `float left` it spans the correct width. I still can't get the gradient to expand over to the left window edge though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you made any changes to your site after **charlietfl's** suggestion but as per the current code in your site you don't need to set the `h1` to `display: inline-block` and `width: auto` because the `h1` and the `.subheader` are already floated to the left. (*Based on your last comment it does seem like you did.*)

The reason why the skewed gradient element doesn't expand till left edge of the window is because the `.container` element has got `padding: 0 90px` set (meaning, there is a `padding` of 90px on the left and right). We can easily remove or override this setting to fix the issue but that would result in a lot of alignment changes within your webpage. Hence the simplest option would be to add a negative `left` position (equal to the padding) to the `h1` and `.subheader` elements like below:

```css
#page-header-bg .subheader,
#page-header-bg h1 {
  left: -90px;
}
```

Alternately, you could also use `transform: translate(...)` to shift the `h1` and `.subheader` to the left by the same no. of pixels as the padding on `.container`. Generally, I would prefer the positioning approach because `transforms` aren't supported by older browsers but since you are already using skew transforms, either of the approaches should be fine.

```css
#page-header-bg .subheader,
#page-header-bg h1 {
  transform: translate(-90px);
}
```

I have not added any demo because there are quite a lot of settings that require to be copied from the actual webpage.

Comment: Awesome solution @Harry. Thanks heaps for your help